# Vertical misalignment due to beamer onslide?

Tags: tables, beamer, vertical-alignment

The following MWE displays the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\onslide<+->
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}r}
 Text\\Text & Text \\\hline
 Text\\Text & Text \\\hline
 Text\\Text & Text \\\hline
\onslide<+->Text & Why too high??\\
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When I remove the \onslide it looks correct. If I change the p{4cm} to say l, the this too works.

How can I get theis last line to be correctly aligned?

Comment: the linked question came up in the automatic "related" list and is essentially identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to avoid specials of any sort (beamer, color,...} at the start of a parbox or p table cell.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\onslide<+->
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}r}
 Text\\Text & Text \\\hline
 Text\\Text & Text \\\hline
 Text\\Text & Text \\\hline
\mbox{}\onslide<+->Text & Why too high??\\
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`p` is `\parbox[t]` so aligns on its top row but a special  before the first row comes *above* the row so is the first thing in the vertical list and sets the alignment of the box. The `\mbox{}` starts the first text line then the special comes *inside* that line so does not affect the alignment point of the vertical list.

Comment: Many thanks. When I did a search, the related question wasn't shown. Assuming it is identical, should I do something?

Comment: @Geoff you don't really need to do anything really: you can accept the answer here (assuming it works) (or not, whichever:-) but probably the question will get closed later so as not to leave too many similar open questions to help focus later searches.