# Alignment of \onslide in tabular

Tags: tables, beamer, vertical-alignment, overlays

Consider this beamer file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
    aaaaaa & \only<2>{aaaaaa} & \onslide+<2>{aaaaaa}
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This input causes slide 2 to look like this:
[image]

Why are the cells not aligned, and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47609/using-beamer-visible-command-inside-a-table-without-adding-vertical-space

Comment: and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109822/vertical-misalignment-due-to-beamer-onslide

Comment: Thank you, @samcarter, adding \hspace{0pt} works nicely.

Comment: @samcarter an answer? :)

Comment: @cmhughes Went for a duplicate instead.

Comment: Cool, nice use of golden badge!