# Vertical misalignment due to beamer onslide

Tags: tables, beamer

I have a simple `tabular` in `beamer` with graphics in the first column.  Whatever I do the vertical alignment in the first column fails.  I also tried to implement the solutions for questions

[Vertical misalignment due to beamer onslide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109822/vertical-misalignment-due-to-beamer-onslide)

[Using beamer \visible command inside a table, without adding vertical space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47609/using-beamer-visible-command-inside-a-table-without-adding-vertical-space)

to no avail.  What should I do to ensure normal vertical alignment?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
name & name \\
\raisebox{-0.8cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}} & text \\[0.85cm]
\uncover<2->{
\raisebox{-0.8cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}} & text \\[0.85cm]}
\uncover<3->{
\raisebox{-0.8cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}} & text}
\end{tabular}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realised that replacing `uncover` with `onslide` (with appropriate synthax change) solves the problem.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
name & name \\
\raisebox{-0.8cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}} & text \\[0.85cm]
\onslide<2->
\raisebox{-0.8cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}} & text \\[0.85cm]
\onslide<3->
\raisebox{-0.8cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}} & text
\end{tabular}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Which is very very strange as according to

[Differences and best practices: \onslide vs. \uncover, \onslide+ vs. \visible, \onslide* vs. \only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61873/differences-and-best-practices-onslide-vs-uncover-onslide-vs-visible)

`onslide` (without a modifier) is simply mapped to `uncover`